# Insufficient Privileges :Error in Generating WSDL File For Salesforce API

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, salesforce

I am trying to get WSDL File For Consuming Salesforce API But As Per their docs here - [generate wsdl docs salesforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_quickstart_steps_generate_wsdl.htm)
After clicking on generate enterprise WSDL i am getting below error page

**Insufficient Privileges**

**You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of the record or your administrator if access is necessary. For more information, see Insufficient Privileges Errors.**

Comment: Whats your question?

Comment: @superfell its quite clear i am unable to generate wsdl file for salesforce api and question is why ? do i missing something . I have logged in as free salesforce developer account . and followed the link (provided in question ) to generate wsdl file ( file required to use their soap api )

Comment: Are you sure you have a developer edition account and not a free trial account [dev edition includes API access, free trial accounts do not]. FWIW, i just signed up a new dev edition account and downloaded the enterprise WSDL fine.

Comment: @superfell
you can see discussion in question - http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/138196/how-to-get-customers-and-opportunities-info-through-salesforce-api

Comment: @superfell i am having Professional Edition . do i need to pay to consume salesforce API . to get opportunities info and customer info .  if you see comments there you will find problem

Comment: You have to buy an API add-on for Prof Edition.

Comment: @superfell thanks i got it found a pdf will be sharing it in answer

Answer (score 0):

To use the APIs you need them to be enabled.

Some editions come with API Access - See [Salesforce editions with API Access](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000005140).

By default a professional edition org doesn't have API access, but it can be purchased as an add-on by contacting your Account Executive.

Once you do have the API enabled, you also need the "API Enabled" Administrative Permission.